# Access platform.properties variables from nbi ant script

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

is it possible to access from the ant script of the nbi (installer project) to variables defined in the *platform.properties* file, like the `nbjdk.active` which is setted when in a project the Java platform is changed?

The goal is from the ant script select one of the packaged jre (32 or 64) in function of this variable.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
this is the build script fragment from when I try to access this variables:

```
<target name="-generate-bundles">
    <for-each property="platform" list="${target.platforms}" separator=" ">

        <condition property="bundle.extention.${platform}" value="exe">
             <contains string="${platform}" substring="windows"/>
        </condition>
        <condition property="bundle.extention.${platform}" value="sh">
             <or>
                 <contains string="${platform}" substring="linux"/>
                 <contains string="${platform}" substring="solaris"/>
             </or>
        </condition>
        <condition property="bundle.extention.${platform}" value="zip">
             <contains string="${platform}" substring="macosx"/>
        </condition>

        <set property="bundle.extention" source="bundle.extention.${platform}"/>

        <create-bundle root="${output.dir}/registry-temp" 
                   platform="${platform}" 
                   target="${bundles.release.dir}/${bundle.files.prefix}-${platform}.${bundle.extention}">
            <component uid="${main.product.uid}" version="1.0.0.0.0"/>


            <!-- HERE I WANT TO CHECK THE VARIABLE AND SELECT ONE OF THE PACKED JRE -->
            <!--<property name="nbi.bundled.jvm.file" value="D:\packed\jre1.8.0_65_32bits\jre.exe"/>-->
            <property name="nbi.bundled.jvm.file" value="D:\packed\jre1.8.0_25_64bits\jre.exe"/>

        </create-bundle>

        <echo>************************</echo>
        <echo>********* OS: ${platform}</echo>
        <echo>********* Arch: ${os.arch}</echo>
        <echo>********* JDK in NB: ${jdk.home}</echo> 
        <echo>********* JDK in platform.properties: HERE I TRY TO ACCESS VARIABLE</echo> 
        <echo>************************</echo>


        <if property="bundle.extention" value="zip">
            <antcall target="zip-to-tgz">
                <param name="input.file"  value="${bundles.release.dir}/${bundle.files.prefix}-${platform}.zip"/>
                <param name="output.file" value="${bundles.release.dir}/${bundle.files.prefix}-${platform}.tgz"/>
            </antcall>
        <delete file="${bundles.release.dir}/${bundle.files.prefix}-${platform}.zip"/>
        </if>
    </for-each>
    <echo>Installer(s) for [${target.platforms}] are available at ${bundles.release.dir}</echo>
</target>
```

and this is the variable in platform.properties file:

```
nbjdk.active=JDK_1.8.0_65-32bits
```

Comment: Can you please show your current build script and exact issue that is being faced?

Comment: Any hint to solve this issue?

Comment: At least I would like if this is possible to achieve, can somebody point me about this?

Comment: Do you mean to access a property from an external property file? What is error that you see?

Comment: I don't see any error, I don't know how to access those variables in the file platform.properties

Comment: Can you check the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the property file contents which are going to be accessed in the build script:

Below build script example shows how to access property `abc` which is from `test.properties` file.

All you need is to load the property file before accessing it as shown in the script using, of course, *change the property file path* as per your environment.

```
<property file="D:/Temp/test.properties"/>
```

Then use `${abc}` whereever its value is needed as shown in the `echo` task below.

**test.properties** contents

```
abc=123
def=234
```

**build.xml**

```
<project name="imported" basedir="." default="test">  
  <property file="D:/Temp/test.properties"/>
  <target name="test" description="check if the property can be retrieved from file">
    <echo message="Property abc's value from file is ${abc}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

**Output**

```
test:
     [echo] Property abc's value from file is 123

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
[Finished in 4.7s]
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not the scope of the question. The question is about in a NetBeans project, if it is possible to access from ant build script to the variables defined in the platform.properties file. If you see the code I attached, I access some environment variables, but any from the platform.properties file.

Comment: The answer shows how access a property from file. And `nbjdk.active` is nowhere referred in the ant script that you provided. Can you be more clear about the problem? error?

Comment: In the line `<echo>********* JDK in platform.properties: HERE I TRY TO ACCESS VARIABLE</echo>`is where I want access this variable.

Comment: Is that a property? then try `${platform.properties}`. If that is file, you first need to load the file as mentioned in the answer.